# Java Homework - Scanner object using next() and nextLine() methods

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a main method to provide a menu for a Contact class and ContactBook class that I wrote for a java class that I am taking.  My issue is that I expected that when the user enters either A, F, P, or Q that my Scanner object (kbd) would capture the input, use it, and move on once the next input is entered.  There is obviously something key that I am not understanding as pushing return doesn't always advance my program as I had expected.  I have included my code and the output.  Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class run{
  public static void main(String[]args){
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean quit = false;
      System.out.println("How many contacts would you like in your Contact Book?: ");
      int size = kbd.nextInt();
      kbd.nextLine();
      ContactBook kevin = new ContactBook(size);
      while(!quit){
         System.out.println("A - Add a contact \n"+
                            "F - Find a contact \n"+
                            "P - Prints the list \n"+
                            "Q - Quits");


         if(kbd.next().equals("A")){
            if(ContactBook.full(kevin))
               System.out.println("Contact book full!");
            else{
               Contact temp = new Contact();
               System.out.println("Enter a First Name: ");
               temp.setFirstName(kbd.nextLine());
               System.out.println("Enter a Last Name: ");
               temp.setLastName(kbd.nextLine());
               System.out.println("Enter a Phone Number: ");
               temp.setPhoneNumber(kbd.nextLine());
               System.out.println("Enter an email: ");
               temp.setEmail(kbd.nextLine());
               kevin.addContact(temp);
            }
         }
         if(kbd.next().equals("F")){
            kevin.search();
         }
         if(kbd.next().equals("P")){
            System.out.print(kevin.produce());
         }
         if(kbd.next().equals("Q")){
            quit = true;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the output that I am getting.

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java run
How many contacts would you like in your Contact Book?: 
3
A - Add a contact 
F - Find a contact 
P - Prints the list 
Q - Quits
A
Enter a First Name: 
Kevin
Enter a Last Name: 
Smith
Enter a Phone Number: 
312-4567
Enter an email: 
kevin@gmail.com



 //here I keep pushing enter and am not sure why it doesn't continue back to
 //the beginning of my while loop



a
a
a
A - Add a contact 
F - Find a contact 
P - Prints the list 
Q - Quits

a

 ----jGRASP: process ended by user.

 ----jGRASP exec: java run
How many contacts would you like in your Contact Book?: 

 ----jGRASP: process ended by user.

 ----jGRASP exec: java run
How many contacts would you like in your Contact Book?: 
4
A - Add a contact 
F - Find a contact 
P - Prints the list 
Q - Quits
A
Enter a First Name: 
Enter a Last Name: 
Smith
Enter a Phone Number: 
312-4567
Enter an email: 
kevin@gmail.com

a
s
d
A - Add a contact 
F - Find a contact 
P - Prints the list 
Q - Quits
```

Again, I am a student and this is for my second Java class.  I have checked many resources in an attempt to understand what I am doing wrong and I haven't been able to piece it together.  Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't call `next()` in each of your `if` statements.

Comment: @Shakedown: your comment should be expanded and should be an answer. It's a too good to be just a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would get rid of all calls to `kbd.next()` and substitute `kbd.nextLine()`. There's no need to use `next()` here, and since it doesn't handle the end of line token, it can mess you up. If you absolutely need to use `kbd.next()`, then be sure to call `kbd.nextLine()` after the call to `next()` to allow your program to handle the end of line token in a rational way.